# Radio Button Selection not refreshing in UI

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

First time radio selection works but if i am selecting radio second time then its not showing as selected. attribute checked=checked showing in html but its not reflection in UI.

What is the solution for this that it can reflect.
Here is script code to apply attribute."

```
  $('#' + myradioid+ ' input:radio').attr("checked", "checked")
```

Here is my html

```
<ul id="Ulist" class="Ulist1">
    <h2 class="QuestionTxt">First question </h2>
    <li id="117184normal" class="statusDefaultAns">
        <a id="117184" href="#" onclick="Select(117184);">
            <h2>
                <input quiz-option="multiple-radio" id="Radio1" type="radio" name="quiz-radio" res="117184">
                <label style="cursor: pointer" for="117184">true</label>

            </h2>
        </a>

    </li>
    <li id="117185normal" class="statusDefaultAns"><a id="117185" href="#" onclick="Select(117185);">
        <h2>
            <input quiz-option="multiple-radio" id="Radio2" type="radio" name="quiz-radio" res="117185">
            <label style="cursor: pointer" for="117185">false</label>

        </h2>
    </a>

    </li>
    <li id="117352normal" class="statusDefaultAns">
        <a id="117352" href="#" onclick="Select(117352);">
            <h2>
                <input quiz-option="multiple-radio" id="Radio3" type="radio" name="quiz-radio" res="117352">
                <label style="cursor: pointer" for="117352">ws</label>

            </h2>
        </a>

    </li>
</ul>
```

Plz provide  a solution for this so that radio selection can refresh in ui.

Thanks
Dalvir

Comment: Try $('#' + myradioid).prop("checked", true);

Comment: you don't need to add other selectors then id, id should be unique: $('#' + myradioid).attr("checked", "checked")

Comment: What do you mean by "selecting radio second time it's not working"? After a post, page reload, second click?

Comment: yes I got my answer. ids was conflicting with input radios. Thanks vli20 to pointing out this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try .prop instead of attr:

```
$('#' + myradioid+ ' input:radio').prop("checked", true)
```

Better yet, try it with the onclick method on the label instead of the line. Selecting something that selects itself could be causing an infinite loop, which would explain your problem. Try this code:

```js
window.Select = function(id) {
    $('#' + id + 'normal input[type="radio"]').click();
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="Ulist" class="Ulist1">
<h2 class="QuestionTxt">First question </h2>    
<li id="117184normal" class="statusDefaultAns"><a id="117184" href="#"><h2>
    <input quiz-option="multiple-radio" id="Radio1" type="radio" name="quiz-radio" res="117184" />
     <label style="cursor:pointer" for="117184" onclick="Select(117184);">true</label></h2></a></li>
<li id="117185normal" class="statusDefaultAns"><a id="117185" href="#"><h2>
    <input quiz-option="multiple-radio" id="Radio2" type="radio" name="quiz-radio" res="117185" />
     <label style="cursor:pointer" for="117185" onclick="Select(117185);">false</label></h2></a></li>
<li id="117352normal" class="statusDefaultAns"><a id="117352" href="#"><h2>
    <input quiz-option="multiple-radio" id="Radio3" type="radio" name="quiz-radio" res="117352" />
     <label style="cursor:pointer" for="117352" onclick="Select(117352);">ws</label></h2></a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: "The difference between attributes and properties can be important in specific situations. Before jQuery 1.6, the .attr() method sometimes took property values into account when retrieving some attributes, which could cause inconsistent behavior. As of jQuery 1.6, the .prop() method provides a way to explicitly retrieve property values, while .attr() retrieves attributes." - http://api.jquery.com/prop/

Comment: True... I usually do, I guess this answer was rather sparse.

Comment: Now there's an answer worthy of a bonus ;) I especially like that you mentioned the normal functionality of radio buttons. The entire javascript seems redundant in the OPs example.